# How can I use .format() with urls in Django?

Tags: python, django, encoding, formatting

I'm writing an app in Django and I would like to format my url in this way:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect("timetable/{0}/{1}/".format(my_grade, my_letter))
```

But it gives me 404 error because path doesn't match.
It's the url I'm redirected to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/timetable/8/%D0%97/
```

How can I fix encoding?

Comment: whats your `my_grade` and `my_letter`

Comment: my_grade = 8, my_letter = "Ь"

Comment: @AlanTheKnight _my_letter = "Ь"_ What is that character?

Comment: @AlanTheKnight Can you share the view that matches that URL?

Comment: @AMC, it's a cyrillic character, nothing really special.

Comment: @funnydman The question is how to format the string. If I use HttpResponseRedirect("timetable/8/Z"), everythin is going to wrok. I just need an ability to change the last two characters in this url, depending on values of two variables.

Answer (score 1):

From [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse)

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

parsed = urlparse("timetable/{0}/{1}/".format(my_grade, my_letter))
url = parsed.path

return HttpRedirect(url)
```

Comment: @AlanTheKnight you mean `"b"` including `""`? If so, have you tried `"\"b\""`?

Answer (score 0):

**Finally I got to the answer.**
The right way was to use urllib.parse.unquote() function which replaces %xx escapes by their single-character equivalent.

```
from urllib.parse import unquote

url = str(my_grade) + '/' + my_letter
url = unquote(url)
return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```